# How can I set timezone UTC+2?

Tags: java, android, date-format, android-date

I ve searched many times but I do not find really what I need,
I write this to find *UTC* time zone :

```
 DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
        df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Istanbul"));
        String gmtTime = df.format(new Date());
        Date gmtTime_ =null;
        try {
            gmtTime_ = df.parse(gmtTime);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

But I need `UTC+2` timezone, How can I get that time zone?

Comment: `TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/GMT+2")` (see this [list](http://garygregory.wordpress.com/2013/06/18/what-are-the-java-timezone-ids/))

Comment: `TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Sofia")`

Comment: thanks for answer, there are two different option about istanbul, **Asia/Istanbul** and **Europe/Istanbul** , but they are both same time, are they different for *java* which one I select?

Comment: I edit my question so Must I write **Locale.getDefault()** to my simpledateformat?

Comment: The names of the time zones depend on the version of the time zone database bundled with your date-time library (with the Java Virtual Machine if you are using the bundled java.util.Date/Calendar). Example, the newly restored name of the Indian city Calcutta is Kolkata. Fresher copies of the time zone database include `Asia/Kolkata` but older ones do not.

Comment: See [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) for more info on time zone names.

Comment: By the way, the hours (and optional minutes) of a time zone offset must be two digits. Using `+2` rather than `+02` will bring you grief.

Comment: @RC No, "Etc/GMT+2" is equivalent to "UTC-02:00"!!! (note the reversed sign)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are willing to switch to a decent date-time library instead of the notoriously troublesome java.util.Date and java.util.Calendar classes bundled with Java, then read the example code below.

The two decent libraries for Java are [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) and the new [java.time package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) bundled with Java 8 (inspired by Joda-Time, defined by [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310)).

## Joda-Time

Here is some example code using Joda-Time 2.3.

```
java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();

// Convert a Date into a Joda-Time DateTime.
// Specify a time zone rather than rely on default.
DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/Istanbul" );
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime( date, timeZone );
DateTime dateTimeUtc = dateTime.withZone( DateTimeZone.UTC );
```

Dump to console…

```
System.out.println( "date: " + date );
System.out.println( "dateTime: " + dateTime );
System.out.println( "dateTimeUtc: " + dateTimeUtc );
```

When run…

```
date: Mon Mar 31 08:13:37 PDT 2014
dateTime: 2014-03-31T18:13:37.314+03:00
dateTimeUtc: 2014-03-31T15:13:37.314Z
```